# ASP.Net MVC2 Routing optional parameter gives 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6, asp.net-mvc-routing

We have the MVC2 mappings...

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "HomeKeepAlive",
  "{controller}/KeepAlive/{objectType}/{id}",
  new { controller = "Home", action="KeepAlive", objectType = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  "DefaultRoute",
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

All servers are Windows Server 2003 sp2, IIS6 with .Net 4 installed.

The routings work on our test server

```
/Home/Ping

/Home/Ping/1

/Home/KeepAlive/Article

/Home/KeepAlive/Article/5
```

But on our live server only urls without an id work, eg

```
/Home/Ping
/Home/KeepAlive/Article
```

whilst those with an id give a 404

```
/Home/Ping/1
/Home/KeepAlive/Article/5
```

Given that the test server works I'm assuming that the problem is a cofiguration issue with IIS6 on our live server, but I can't see any differences between them.

Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: The live server is a site in IIS, whereas the test server is a virtual directory.

Comment: I have a simple workaround. Add an extra 'dummy' url parameter. On the live server the id url parameter now gets recognised eg \Home\Ping\1 now works. If you try \Home\Ping\1\2 it gives a 404, but I don't have any urls with the extra parameter.
            
I still don't understand why the live server has this behaviour. It doesn't fill me with confidence.
The new mapping is...             
routes.MapRoute(
 "Default",
 "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{dummy}",
 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =   UrlParameter.Optional, dummy= UrlParameter.Optional }
);

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx) for a bug in ASP.net, introduced recently, that may be causing your problem.

Comment: Interesting. We're MVC2 not 3, but I'll try creating separate routes for with id, and without id. Having said that, it works fine on the test server.

Comment: The bug is not really with MVC, but System.Web.Routing. Creating two routes will solve your problem.

Comment: Two routes doesn't fix it. It still doesn't pick up the routes that take an id. Maybe it'll be easier after a good night's sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/)

Comment: Thanks. I'd used Steve's book as the basis for setting the servers up.